# Java Multi-threading producer-consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

Following this code, how to implement multithread between send records and get records.

```
public class Test_ProducerConsumer {  

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Send records
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            kafka_io.send_records(sendtopic, "test_key", "test_value" + String.valueOf(i));         
        }

        // Get records
        try {
            kafka_io.get_records(gettopic, 100000);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

On the side of receiving the items, you can block the thread till a new item has came, while with any other thread you can add the item and notify the thread who is receiving the items.

```java
// Inside a class
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = Consumer()
    Thread t = Thread(r)
    t.start()

    // Send records
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        r.queue.add(DataWrapper(...));         
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<DataWrapper> queue = BlockingQueue();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            DataWrapper data = queue.take();
            // use data here
        }
    }
}

class DataWrapper {
    String dataString;   // these are your variables change as you want
    int dataInt;
}
```

Comment: Since the variable is called `kafka_io` there is probably already a message queue in place.